# Bio probability problem: conditional probability

Tags: probability

According to a study, 12% of the world population has diabetes mellitus. 
Suppose there are two methods to diagnose this condition: the method A gives a positive result for 80% of the people with diabetes and for 10% of the patients without the disease, while method B gives a positive result for 70% of the people with diabetes and for 5% without the disease.

What is the probability of a random person to get get a positive result on both methods? (i.e. calculate $P(A_+ \cap B_+)$).

I have already tried to do this ($D_+$ means the person has diabetes):

$P(A_+ \cap B_+) = [P(A_+|D_+) + P(A_+|D_-)] * [P(B_+|D_+) + P(B_+|D_-)]$

$P(A_+ \cap B_+) = [(0.8)(0.12) + (0.1)(0.88)] * [(0.7)(0.12) + (0.05)(0.88)]$

But this does not lead me to the right answer on my textbook. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Do the methods provide independent results?

Comment: Yes, they are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming enough independence of A and B given D, you might try $$P(A_+ \cap B_+) = P(A_+\mid D_+)P(B_+\mid D_+)P(D_+) + P(A_+\mid D_-)P(B_+\mid D_-)P(D_-)$$

Comment: Yes, this is totally correct!! :D :D But how did you think in order to get to this expression??

Comment: It expands $P(A_+\cap B_+) = P(A_+\cap B_+\mid D_+)P(D_+) + P(A_+\cap B_+\mid D_-)P(D_-)$, which is a standard conditional probability expression